# How to to center selected text in QTextBrowser

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlineedit, qtextbrowser

The code posted below creates `QTextBrowser` window filling it with 100 lines of text: starting from `MESSAGE-0000` all the way to `MESSAGE-0099`

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication([])

textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
for i in range(100):
    textBrowser.insertPlainText('MESSAGE-%04d'%i + '\n')

textBrowser.show()
app.exec_()
```

Question: How to find a line number where its text says: `MESSAGE-0051`, then select or highlight it and then scroll to it so the selected-highlightet line is positioned at the top edge of the `QTextBrowser` window, so the result would look like this:

[image]

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search backwards, it will automatically scroll the selected line to the top of the viewport:

```
textBrowser.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
textBrowser.find('MESSAGE-0051', QtGui.QTextDocument.FindBackward)
```

(Of course, if you search for say, `MESSAGE-0095`, it won't put the selected line at the top, because the view cannot scroll down that far).